# How to change gnome3 shadow effect

Tags: shadow, gnome-3

I runs gnome3 in lastest archlinux, the windows shandow effects is hardly to see, how can I zoom out the shadow effects like OSX?

Answer (score 0):

It says [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/2achwa/tweaking_mutter_window_shadows/) that it is hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

edit file .profile in the home direcotry, and add the following line:

export MUFFIN_NO_SHADOWS=1;

Then log out and back in.